# Discord bot can't mention everyone despite having its permission

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is the sendMessage function:

```
async def sendMessage(color, title, value, should_delete=True, channel=""):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
    embed.add_field(name=title, value=value, inline=False)
    if channel == "":
        msg = await client.send_message(message_obj.channel, embed=embed)
    else:
        msg = await client.send_message(client.get_channel(channel), embed=embed)
    if should_delete:
        await delete_msg(msg)
```

The bot can mention anyone but everyone and here. Despite having mention everyone permission.

```
sendMessage(OK_COLOR_HASH, "title", "Hello @everyone")
```

**Edit:** When I converted the message type to the normal one instead of embed one, it worked.

Comment: Do you see an error?  Is the `everyone` role set to be mentionable in the server configurations?  I don't see where in this code you're actually adding the mention, could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: No error since it just can't mention, just normally in the message content. And here is an example: sendMessage(OK_COLOR_HASH, "title", "Hello @everyone")

Comment: Try using the `mention` attribute of the `Role` object: `f"Hello {server.default_role.mention}"`

Comment: The problem is the message should be customized, will check format attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to sending a mention to everyone through the `default_role` attribute

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def evy(msg):
    await bot.say(msg.message.server.default_role)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this block code. `roles` return a list all guild's roles, but first role always a default guild role (`default_role`) and that's why you must use slicing function.

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.guild.roles[0])
```

Or you can do something like this.

```
 @bot.command()
 async def test(ctx):
     await ctx.send(ctx.message.guild.default_role)
```