# How do I mention @everyone in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I mention `@everyone` in discord.py? Yes, the bot has all the permissions required.
I tried the basic:

```py
await ctx.send("@everyone")
```

And from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64922138/11088461):

```py
await ctx.send(ctx.message.guild.default_role)
```

Both times, the bot did indeed send a `@everyone` message, however, it is just a message, there is no actual ping. I checked my inbox and asked others too. See image:

[image: Actual Ping] [image: Bot Ping]

The first is an actual ping and it shows up in my inbox too, however, the second is the bot ping and it's just text.

What am I doing wrong here? and How should I ping `@everyone`?

Comment: Are you sure your bot has the perms to mention everyone?

Comment: @F.M Yes, I even gave it administrator role.

Comment: Hmm, I tried `await ctx.send(ctx.message.guild.default_role)` and it works for me: https://pastebin.com/8VtTnwfs

Comment: @F.M I have no idea why it is not working for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After looking around in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AllowedMentions), here is what worked for me:

```py
allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = True)
await ctx.send(content = "@everyone", allowed_mentions = allowed_mentions)
```

You can also set `AllowedMentions.all` to allow everything.

Comment: You can pass the `allowed_mentions` kwarg in the bot constructor if you don't want to pass them into every `Messageable.send` method

Answer (score -6):

You have to add a specific property when initializing the bot:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: False});
```

Comment: This throws the error `NameError: name 'disableEveryone' is not defined`. Also the bot is in discord.py

Comment: This looks to be targeted at Javascript.

Comment: Isn't `disableEveryone` supposed to be in quotes?